# Comparison failure between a variable string and a context param value using fn:startsWith

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web.xml, context-param

With the following piece of code, if `s_dlText` starts with the string `"Shipping costs"`, the code inside the `c:when` instruction is executed (the  word `"Pass1"` appears in the resulting page):

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${fn:startsWith(s_dlText, 'Shipping costs') == true}">
    <br />
    Pass1
    <br />
  </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Whereas in the following case and again, if `s_dlText` starts with the string `"Shipping costs"`, the code inside the `c:when` instruction is not executed (the  word `"Pass2"` does NOT appear in the resulting page):

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${fn:startsWith(s_dlText, S_SHIPPING_COSTS) == true}">
    <br />
    Pass2
    <br />
  </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

`S_SHIPPING_COSTS` is declared as follows in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>S_IF_MSG_SHIPPING_COSTS</param-name>
  <param-value><![CDATA[Shipping costs]]></param-value>
</context-param>
```

Do you see what's not being done the right way? Thanks.

NOTE 1

Note that, if I remove the `<![CDATA[]]>` markup, the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :  `<c:when test="${fn:startsWith(s_dlText, initParam.S_SHIPPING_COSTS)}">` and you do not need `<![CDATA[]]>` markup in your web.xml